# Rebind Ctrl+Alt+Tab

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, pantheon

Just a quick question. I have a Logitech MX Master mouse and the thumb button on it is bound by default to Ctrl+Alt+Tab. In Elementary, this looks to do nothing but unfocus my current window. I was looking for a way to rebind this but any change I make in the Keyboard section of Settings to bind something else to this combo does not change it. Even after the rebind the key combination does the same thing.

Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing? I can't find where Ctrl+Alt+Tab is even bound in the Keyboard section to replace it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Erik

Answer (score 1):

I found it! The answer was yes, I was missing something. This is a gnome bound key combination to switch panels. I found the setting using:

`gsettings list-recursively | grep -i Tab`

and replaced it by using

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels "['<Control><Alt><Super>Tab']"`

Then, since Gnome wasn't overriding my Key Combination, Control+Alt+Tab now does what I bound it to!

I don't know if this is possible, but could Elementary detect duplicates of these Key Combinations at the Gnome Settings level as well? I think when you bind key combinations there are checks for duplicates, but I assume they don't extend to these Gnome key combinations since I could set this hotkey but it just didn't override. Elementary Staff, is this something that could even be done?

All the best!
-Erik